# html expand element/form on text input

Tags: html, forms, layer

I like a form in html 5 that can expand on the text typed in the input. For example if i enter a post box adress in a contact form I would like to the form expand it to include a delivery address to. So if the word "BOX" excists in the adress1 line in the form it would expand with a adress2 line.

So my question  what type of coding sould i use? Do I need javascript or can this be done by css, jquery?

I have serached the web and found lots of code for switching layers on/off but none that takes the input as trigger for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need Jquery (so you need JS of course) you simply use smth like:

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});
```

Obviously you can execute any finctionality in {}.